# How to select and echo MySQL data (one to many) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current code, it works fine with one problem.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tmdb_movies JOIN genres ON genres.genres_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id 
  ");
     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();
     // Pick up the result as an array
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
     foreach ($result as $row) {
    print "".$row["movie_title"]." ".$row["genres_name"] ."   ".$row["cast_name"] ."<br/>";
}
```

The thing is, I am trying to echo Movie Name and it's Genres.

What I want to echo:

> The Dark Knight - Action, Crime, Drama

What the code echo:

> The Dark Knight - Action
>
> The Dark Knight - Crime
>
> The Dark Knight - Drama

Screenshot of main movie table http://prntscr.com/fokwip

and Screenshot of genres movie table http://prntscr.com/fokwoy

Comment: I think the problem is in your query

Comment: How so? @kielou sir

Comment: have you tested your query manually? just to see what is the result in your query

Comment: What you mean? I wrote what the code echo above

Comment: can you include an example of your table in your post.

Comment: Screenshot of main movie table @kielou http://prntscr.com/fokwip

and Screenshot of genres movie table http://prntscr.com/fokwoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo what you want you can change your sql query :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genres_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre_concat FROM tmdb_movies JOIN genres ON genres.genres_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title");

//  sql strict group by

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.cast_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre_concat FROM tmdb_movies JOIN genres ON genres.genres_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.cast_name ORDER BY tmdb_movies.movie_title");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row) {
        print "".$row["movie_title"]." ".$row["genre_concat"] ."   ".$row["cast_name"] ."<br/>";}
```

GROUP_CONCAT allows to concat all the different genre for each unique movie title.

More Documentation :

GROUP BY : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

GROUP_CONCAT : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'genre_concat' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in 1st line

Comment: 2 errors: `Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given ` (in 1st line of your code)

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in` in 2nd line of your code

Comment: I have 18 columns in main tmdb_movies table, i group them all?

Comment: Retry, I did a mistake with "" and ''. You only need to group the column you want to be unique.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'genres.genre_names' in 'field list' in ` your code's 2nd line

Comment: My friend told me this, i will quote it 
`The new (5.7+) MySQL grouping rules are stricter than the older ones so all columns except the functions need to be mentioned in the group by `

Comment: It depends of your sql mode, replace genre_names with the correct column name genre_names, and that might work

Comment: new error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'KC_movies.tmdb_movies.movie_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in `

Comment: Yeah I've edited so it should be all right. If you are in full strict mode group by, it means that you need to group by all the column you're selecting. See edited answer for that

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #20 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'KC_movies.genres.genres_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in `

Comment: I grouped all columns in tmdb_movie table

Comment: It's not going to work, try to the second query I've put in my answer. You should always only select the fields you need rather than "*"

Comment: Worked but one problem @bdloul sir. 

The genres are getting echo'ed 2 times: Like: 

`The Dark Knight Action, Action, Crime, Crime, Drama, Drama`

Comment: And they are getting echo'ed in alphbatical order (movie_title)

Comment: I've edited my answer, ORDER BY for the order and DISTINCT for unique field

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `group_cancat` like that:

```
SELECT
    tmdb_movies.*, group_concat(genres.genres_name) as genres_names
FROM
    tmdb_movies 
JOIN 
    genres 
ON 
    genres.genres_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
GROUP BY 
    tmdb_movies.movie_id
```

And then prints it:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "{$row['movie_title']} - {$row['genres_names']}<br/>";
}
```

Alternative SQL(it seems better than above sql):

```
SELECT
    tmdb_movies.*, temp.genres_names
FROM
    tmdb_movies 
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            genres_tmdb_id, group_concat(genres_name) as genres_names 
        FROM 
            genres
        GROUP BY 
            genres_tmdb_id
    ) temp 
    ON 
       temp.genres_tmdb_id = tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Btw i have 18 columns in main tmdb_movies table. So i select them all in groupby command??? like u did with tmdb_movies.id??

Comment: 18 columns not rows** sorry

Comment: @JohnDoo I though I misunderstand that. You need create another table to store  the relation between of `movie` and `genre`, not in the `movie` table.

Comment: No, the columns in tmdb_movies table are not related to genres. They are like: Budget, Revenue, Release date...The table structure is right

Comment: @JohnDoo According to your table struct, I have modified SQL(jsut changed `id` to `movie_id`), and executed it, got the correct result. Feel free to try it again.